# Why my redux state always return with default case?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using react-redux but I can't see my state. And when I check for my state it always returns my default value. I check my type but its return true value. Where is the problem ? Thanks for help

My Action :

```
import { 
  SET_MENULIST
} from "../constants/Menu";

export const makeMenu = (menuList) => {
  return {
    type: SET_MENULIST,
    menuList,
  };
};
```

My Reducer :

```
const menu = (state = {}, action) => { 

  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_MENULIST:
      return {
        menuList: action.menuList,
      };
 
    default:
      return "err";
  }
};
export default menu;
```

My reducer/index.js (combineReducers) :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import Auth from "./Auth";
import Theme from "./Theme";
import Menu from "./Menu";
const reducers = combineReducers({
  theme: Theme,
  auth: Auth,
  menu: Menu,
});

export default reducers;
```

I trying use it like `makeMenu(data);`  on my page and testing it like :

```
const test = useSelector((state) => state.menu);
 console.log(test) //Its returns "err" (Default value of my reducer
```

)

Where is the mistake ? Thanks for replies!!!

Comment: How did you dispatch `makeMenu(data)` action?

Comment: @slideshowp2 i think i didnt dispatch it. maybe thats why its not working. I just import it from actions then tried use it.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible, complete code example?

Comment: What is the type of `SET_MENULIST`?

Comment: I import my SET_MENULIST from constant. In constant its :

`export const SET_MENULIST = "SET_MENULIST";`

Comment: Also probably what you want to do in the reducer is return
`{...state,  menuList: action.menuList}`
And same for default:
`return state`

Comment: Can you include how you call `makeMenu` function

Comment: @SinanYaman i call it like :

  `import { makeMenu } from "../../../../redux/actions/Menu";`

Comment: @SergeiKlinov i tried use like as u said too but its still same. returning empty object. Because my initialValue is empty object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Couple of things to be changed:

#### Dispatching the action

From where you call the `makeMenu` function, you have to dispatch the action.
Example:

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import {makeMenu} from './path/to/makeMenu'

const ComponentExample = props => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  dispatch(makeMenu(menuList)) /* call this wherever you want to call makeMenu */

}
```

#### Bonus: Returning from reducer

When you return a new object from the reducer like this, you will override other values, so a potential error.

```
case SET_MENULIST:
      return {
        menuList: action.menuList,
      };
```

You might want to use the spread operator:

```
case SET_MENULIST:
      return {
        ...state,
        menuList: action.menuList,
      };
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its worked! But can i ask extra question ? Some peoples dispatch it without useDispatch. On my example project they just using function name like : makeMenu(data) and its working. How it can be possible ? I mean without useDispatch?

Comment: You can wrap your redux with a middleware. Check out redux-thunk. When you use `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` you can do that. However, I would go for hooks, like `useDispatch`, if you are wondering about my personal opinion.

Comment: thank you so much. You helped me a lot! I will going to use useDispatch as you said but i ask it because i wonder :) Thank you again and have a great day!

Comment: No problem, happy coding!